# How to improve speed when using GCP SQL as a service

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, server, saas

We are currently hosting our website on a dedicated server and decided to migrate our database (CMS and CRM) to GCP's SQL for several reasons (connection to big query, data analysys, etc), unfortunately each query makes a new requets to the SQL service and it is slowing down the website dramatically. How can the speed be improved? We sould expect Google to offer an incredible speed for such service but it is not the case.

On our local PHP connection we simply connect using the database name, username, passsword and host IP.

Comment: More details are required. Do not use terms like `slow`. Specify what is slow using measurements. Include common items for both the VM and Cloud SQL such as zone, instance size, disk size, and memory. There are many factors that can affect performance. Some are easily improved by selecting the correct region and zone, correct instance size, disk size (larger disks are faster), memory size, etc. Some items require analysis and database optimization (query analysis, indexing, etc).

Comment: Since you mention PHP and MySQL I am guessing you have selected a small size for the Compute Engine instance and the smallest size for Cloud SQL. If that is the case, you are using test and development configurations. Moving from test and development sizes to production levels will have a big impact. Another important item is to have both in the same zone or at least in the same region. That reduces network latencies.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the query what it is doing ? Try to get the QPS your mysql instance can support. Also, worth taking a look at concurrent requests, your MySQL is currently handling and try to increase it if necessary